# Process does not change a field upon creation

Tags: process-builder

Upon creating a new Quote, under certain conditions a field on Quote Line Items should change. Now it does change, but only upon editing an already existing Quote. When creating a new Quote, the field remains the same (the field is Boolean default 0, intended value upon creation is 1).

Could that be that when creating a new Quote, the fields for the object Quote Line Items have not been created yet? How to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

> Could that be that when creating a new Quote, the fields for the object Quote Line Items have not been created yet?

That's it precisely. Like all child objects, Quote Line Items cannot be created until their parent, the Quote, is in place.

There are a few other solutions, depending on exactly what you're aiming to do. The most obvious to me, assuming that the Quote Line Item field should be set once and then should not change based on updates to the Quote, is that your Process needs to be on the Quote Line Item object rather than the Quote.

One thing to be aware of is that functions like `ISNEW()` in a Quote Line Item process apply to the Quote Line Item, not the Quote. You'll need to figure out how to phrase your business requirements so that they can be evaluated in the context of creating the Line Item itself.

Comment: Thanks David, you certainly know your stuff!